# AWS can't assign Role to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance based in N.Virginia

I want to automate the start and the stop of the instance, to reduce costs.

To do that, I've created a Role that inherits Policies, and a lambda function that is triggered by a cloudwatch event that starts and stops the server.

The last step to do is to assign the role that I've created, to the EC2 instance.

So I go to instances, select the appropriate instance, and go to Modify IAM Role. However, the problem that I'm encountering is that I cannot find the IAM Role that I've created previously to assign it to the EC2 instance.

I've seen that roles are not region-specific anymore. They are global now.
If I go to the Roles section, I'm able to see the role. However that role is not available in the drop-down menu in the Modify Role section of the EC2 instance.

The permission policies that the created role has:

[image]

And this is the json for the permissions:

[image]

Regarding the Role, it just the trusted relationships set like this:

[image]

And still, the Role is not visible from the EC2 Instance to assign it.

Can you help me find a solution?

Any clues?

Comment: Could you add information about your Role Trust Policy ? You cannot use just any roles as your EC2 roles.

Comment: Done Nicolas. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Updated the post with some snapshots from the Trust relationships.

Comment: I know I'm sidestepping your issue, but I don't see how the instance role really helps you here.  The instance can't *start* itself if it's not already running, and if the instance wants to *stop* itself, you can just `shutdown -h now` and the VM will stop.   For neither of those operations is the instance role required.  The *lambda* needs those permissions, not the instance.

Comment: I created a lambda function for that purpose. The function will start and stop the instance.

Comment: Yeah, so the instance doesn't need those permissions.  The lambda does.  The relationship between the permissions and the instance is the `Resource` section of the policy.  Your resource is `*`, so the lambda can start and stop any instance.  Why does the instance need the role?

Comment: "roles are not region-specific anymore"   They were never region specific, for what it's worth.  "... I'm able to see the role ...  not available in the drop-down menu".   It's not always clear why the aws web console does what it does.  If the EC2 web console supports creating a new role, you might want to try reverse engineering: create a new role through the EC2 web console, then compare your role with the one EC2 created.

Comment: "The permission policies that the created role has" I also noticed the policy you show in the image is attached to 0 entities.  I believe that count should include the role to which it's supposedly attached.  But maybe the screenshot is just out of date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257046/discussion-between-juan-m-and-erik258).

Comment: Why are you trying to attach the IAM role to the EC2 instance? You seem to be saying that the Lambda function will stop/start the instance(s) so the role needs to be attached to the Lambda function, not the EC2 instance. And the trust policy needs to allow lambda.amazonaws.com.

Answer (score 0):

In order to start and stop an EC2 instance, it's incorrect to assign a role to the EC2 instance.

Instead, what It has to be done is:

- Create a lambda function (either one that switches states, or one for starting and one for stopping).
- Assign a role with inline permissions to access the resources.
- Set up Eventbridge Rules, for automation.

This could be the code for an EC2-Start function:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    instances = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:AutoStop', 'Values': ['True']}])
    for reservation in instances.get("Reservations"):
        for instance in reservation.get("Instances"):
            instance_id = instance['InstanceId']
            state = instance['State']['Name']
            if state == 'stopped':
                ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
                print('Started instance: ' + instance_id)
```

And this could be the code for an EC2-Stop function:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    instances = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:AutoStop', 'Values': ['True']}])
    for reservation in instances.get("Reservations"):
        for instance in reservation.get("Instances"):
            instance_id = instance['InstanceId']
            state = instance['State']['Name']
            if state == 'running':
                ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
                print('Stopped instance: ' + instance_id)
```

The Role for each one, found in the Configuration tab, could be a role with 3 permissions, or 2 roles with two permissions each.
If you would like a more granular implementation, this could be the permissions for the EC2Start Role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This only contains permission to EC2 DescribeInstances, which allows to filter with the conditions of the tag: AutoStop, and for starting instances. The tag should be set to the target EC2 instances you want to start/stop. You can change the name of the tag to whichever you prefer.

The permissions for the EC2Stop Role should look like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

As it can be seen, these are two separated permissions in order to be more specific. One possible alternate way would be to define one privacy policy with both permissions included, like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and assign to both Roles (Start & Stop). Or copy the same code in both in-line permissions.

Last, set EventBridge Rules for automation.
I set up two, one for starting and the other for stopping the EC2 instance.

This is my schedule, but you can implement the way it fits best for you:
[image]

Finally, define the target of the EventBridge Rule (i.e.: what will be called when the schedule is met). I set that a Lambda Function will be called and that lambda function will be either the Starting or Stopping function. (in the picture below you can see that the target lambda function is EC2-Start-Function because I've chosen to use the separate lambda functions approach).

[image]

Finally, as a bonus track, I set up two bash scripts in my computer in order to call these two lambda functions on demand, in case I need to start or stop the instance manually (this avoids to log into the IAM console)

First I've downloaded the AWS CLI from here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html
I'm using macOS so I've clicked on that.

Then I configured the aws configuration with: `$ aws configure`

You should have already created a user with the role that allows it to run lambda functions. The permissions should look like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and created an Access Key from the console (you will need to supply this during aws configure).

Another parameter that you will have to configure is the AWS region. I've used the default which is us-east-1, but depends on what you've chosen during master account set up.

When you have aws cli configured, you could create a script with the following code:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name NAME-OF-YOUR-FUNCTION output.txt | grep 'StatusCode' | cut -d ':' -f 2 - | sed 's/[ ",]//g' | sed 's/^/La salida es: /'
```

This will invoke the lambda function named: NAME-OF-YOUR-FUNCTION and capture the statusCode and print it out to the console.
You could create another script for the Stopping of the instance, where you call the appropriate lambda function created as stated above.

Hope this helps someone else, like me, that is starting with the AWS cloud world and stumble upon many bumps in the road.

jmt